# Select and crawl content from a certain area

Tags: php

This isn't a question of which I have no code but just a basic question to ask. 
I know quite a lot of PHP and have begun writing web crawlers for certain projects and have wondered if there is a way to only crawl data in a certain area.

I am thinking about creating a sports-score type web app and i know some websites which keep the scores in a box on the right hand side, is there a way I could just crawl the data from that specific area and not the whole web page?

It was just a question

Comment: It's not possible. Unless the website has some sort of an API for fetching the data, then you would have to read the entire webpage.